# Prevent device from using static IP not assigned by dnsmasq's DHCP server

Tags: networking, 13.04, proxy, dhcp

I am trying to mimic the functionality of ClearOS, a Red Hat based gateway/content filter. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 desktop on a PC with two NICs.

So I have installed dansguardian and squid and I also installed the full dnsmasq package so I can use it as a DHCP server. These are the same packages ClearOS uses. My setup is working well except for one issue.

In dnsmasq.conf, I statically assigned 192.168.1.4 to the MAC address of my PC. I do this because I configured the proxy/content filter to allow myPC to bypass the filter, based on its IP address.

However, I turned off myPC and went to another PC (call it kidsPC) and manually configured kidsPC with the same address (192.168.1.4). Oops, kidsPC can bypass the proxy/content filter.

With ClearOS, when I did the above, the gateway would not allow traffic from kidsPC to the internet. It somehow detected that I've already statically assigned this address to another device's MAC.

Is it possible to mimic the ClearOS behavior? Is there a setting I'm missing? The forums at ClearOS don't seem eager to help me. I've googled and can't find an answer.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly am no expert in using squid, but i think you might benefit not using the ip address in the acl proxy/content filter, but use the MAC instead.

I presume you have something like the following to identify your computer:

```
acl myPC src 192.168.1.4
```

Try to change it to the following (where the 00:00:00:00:00:00 is your MAC-address)

```
acl myPC arp 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

This way the IP does not really matter, only the MAC is used as a criteria.